# How does a hash index relate to the array size?

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, hash, hashmap

I'm making a program to read the strings from a file into a hash table using separate chaining and I want to use the [djb2](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/~oz/hash.html) hash algorithm. When, for example, I hash the word "welcome" I get a hash index of 7573091155873627. Does this mean that the array that holds my hash table needs to be this gargantuan? I only really expect to read about 100 words or so. I just want to be sure that I can have my hash table set to hold 100 items and still use this algorithm.

Comment: Please consider the remainder operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put an entry into the array of a hash table, the bucket you choose is

```
hashvalue modulo size of the array
```

Si there is no problem having extremely large hash value. On the contrary, they allow you to use arbitrary large arrays, which allows you to hash any number of items. Actually, in standard implementation, the size of the array grows when the hash array becomes too full.

Comment: So even if my hash table array only is meant to hold 10 items, I can still use a hash index that's over 6 trillion?

Comment: the number of collisions generated by this method is proportional to the size of the array in question.

Comment: Yes. The remainder of 623492309482348 is a number in [0..9]

Comment: @Josh in that case using a hash will be pointless, but it can be done.

Comment: @emcas88 yeah it was just an example